# Call Microsoft Graph API from Actionable Message

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to send an email using Microsoft Graph API from an action in an actionable message. (So send an email from a button in an email) However I'm always receiving a 401 Error. I tested the graph API in normal setting and the Auth token is valid, but here it seems to work differently.

Is it possible at all to achieve this?

```
{
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.0",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "ActionSet",
            "id": "f8d6ddb5-ed34-e8e4-59ec-73084e885bbb",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "type": "Action.Http",
                    "id": "6a807e29-1023-ed90-713a-94209c847c7b",
                    "title": "Envoyer",
                    "url": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendMail",
                    "style": "positive",
                    "isPrimary": true,
                    "method": "POST",
                    "headers": [
                        {
                            "name": "Authorization",
                            "value": "Bearer ..."
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Content-Type",
                            "value": "application/json"
                        }
                    ],
                    "body": "..."
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "padding": "None",
    "@type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "@context": "http://schema.org/extensions"
}
```

(Edit)
This is how I get the token:

```
Providers.globalProvider = new TeamsProvider ({
    clientId: {my client id},
    authPopupUrl: '/auth.html'
});
const token = await Providers.globalProvider.getAccessToken({scopes: ['Mail.Send', 'Mail.ReadWrite']});
```

Comment: Do you have permissions(Mail.Send) in your access token? How did you get the token?

Comment: I have the Mail.Send permission yes. I added the code used to get the access token.

Comment: I didn't play with Teams SDK but Try using https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userid}/sendMail as your graph call and see if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same result with graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users{userid}/sendMail

Comment: I compared the token received from the Teams Provider with the one from MSAL and they're both the same. It works when called from the Teams app code, but not in the HttpAction of an Actionable message.

Comment: I tried with Adaptive card playground and its working for me. But i haven't tested the same with Microsoft Teams.

Comment: Hi @Vincent Gagnon Currently teams does not support http card action. Please go through this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-actions) for supported card actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of how you generate the Adaptive Card, you cannot use the Microsoft Graph API from the context of Outlook using Outlook Actionable Messages :
https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/5674

Answer (score 0):

Currently teams does not support http card action. Please go through this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-actions) for supported card actions.

Comment: The documentation mentioned is for bots and messaging extensions in Teams. This would be the right documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/send-via-email